# let users run program as administrator - windows xp 'sudoers'?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-xp

On linux I could just add a entry like `username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/program` to the sudoers file to enable my users to run a program with root/administrator-privileges.

How can I do something like this on windows?

I know there are tools like CPAU which may create wrapper-programs which contain a obfuscated version of the password, but since obfuscation is no real security that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: This does prompt for the password though doesn't it? As already shown in the sudoers entry, I need this to be unattended as it is a regular task in a large network.

Comment: There isn't really any equivalent mechanism. You're kinda stuck with either creating a user to run that regular (scheduled?) task with the desired rights or nothing.

Comment: Why does the program require admin priv?  Typically even programs that say they require admin rights are just being lazy and you can grant the proper regkey access, file access, etc. necessary to run the app as a standard user.

Comment: As it's a rundll32 system-call I don't think there is a way around.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  If this is a software update, there are other tools that do that (group policy, PsExec, LANdesk, Altiris Deployment Solution or Altiris Software Delivery, etc.).

If it's a legacy app that your business requires, programs often lie about what they need.  You can usually give the proper file/registry access without admin privileges.

If you're in an Active Directory environment, you could use [Beyond Trust Powerbroker Desktops](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBrokerForWindows/), a group policy plug-in that gives install privileges to processes rather than users (for example, it gives your legacy app "admin" privileges instead of the users). However, depending on the application, even that might give more privileges than you want.

If this is a regular scheduled task instead of an interactive program, you might want to look at things like PsExec, Group Policy, Task Scheduler, etc.

Comment: I already pointed out that it involves a rundll32 system-call so there is no way around having administrator privileges. Also, as no AD is involved I can't use that plugin. As it isn't a scheduled but a interactive task, the mentioned tools don't help either.

Comment: Well.  If you did have AD, the plugin would be exactly what you're looking for, alas.  You can do group policy without AD, but I don't know if the plugin would work like that, and it would be a ginormous pain.  We once had to deploy policy changes--local password policies, etc.--without AD to 3000 workstations.  This involved management software and a script that did cruel and unusual things (blew away all policy and rebuilt it).  You might be able to do something like that, but it would hurt.  :(